# Consumer connect errors from AWS MSK via IAM - SSL problem or something else?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

```
"thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-groupId-1-1, groupId=groupId-1] Initiating connection to node node.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9098 (id: -2 rack: null) using address node.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/10.x.x.x"}
"thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-groupId-1-1, groupId=groupId-1] Set SASL client state to SEND_APIVERSIONS_REQUEST"}
"thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-groupId-1-1, groupId=groupId-1] Creating SaslClient: client=null;service=kafka;serviceHostname=node.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com;mechs=[AWS_MSK_IAM]"}
"thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"Setting SASL/AWS_MSK_IAM client state to SEND_CLIENT_FIRST_MESSAGE"}
"thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-groupId-1-1, groupId=groupId-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 65562, SO_SNDBUF = 131124, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -2"}
"thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-groupId-1-1, groupId=groupId-1] Completed connection to node -2. Fetching API versions."}
"thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-groupId-1-1, groupId=groupId-1] Connection with node.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/10.x.x.x disconnected","stack_trace":"java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer\n\tat sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(FileDispatcherImpl.java)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:356)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.readFromSocketChannel(SslTransportLayer.java:228)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:291)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:178)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:246)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.coordinatorUnknownAndUnready(ConsumerCoordinator.java:459)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1584)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1559)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1360)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1274)\n\t... 4 frames truncated\n"}

"level":"DEBUG","logger_name":"o.a.k.common.network.SslTransportLayer","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[SslTransportLayer channelId=-2 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=node.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/10.x.x.x:9098], selector=sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@690f136f, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] Failed to send SSL Close message","stack_trace":"java.io.IOException: Unexpected status returned by SSLEngine.wrap, expected CLOSED, received OK. Will not send close message to peer.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:194)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:974)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:155)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:955)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:939)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:625)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:246)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.coordinatorUnknownAndUnready(ConsumerCoordinator.java:459)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:487)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1584)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1559)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1360)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1274)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-09-29 08:05:12.245-0700","level":"INFO","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-groupId-1-1, groupId=groupId-1] Node -2 disconnected."}
```

I have attempted to follow all the directions from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/securing-apache-kafka-is-easy-and-familiar-with-iam-access-control-for-amazon-msk/).

Ive tested my iam policy using `aws kafka <various>` .

Ive checked that port 9098 is open.

My policy has everything permitted. If I can get this working I'll deal with limiting permissions later.

Just trying to get a consumer to start at this point.

Suggestions on where to look for the issue?

---

## Edit:

Added some ssl debug to the call. Am seeing CLIENTHELLO being sent but nothing back from the server. Just the auth failure.

Using `openssl s_client -connect <host> -tls1_2` I was able to get a "Verify return code: 0 (ok)" from the server

---

## More:

I think something is blocking the SSL request:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
```

I can view the open port via NMAP so Im not sure what's happening there either.

---

Just to close this off: I think MSK doesn't allow iam auth from outside a VPC. I was able to get my test working from EKS but not otherwise.